# How to remove image in wxPython

Tags: wxpython

I am trying to remove an image that has been placed at some random point on a panel. This solution works but it is dependent upon the colour scheme that I am using. Is there a better way of doing this?

```
import wx
from PIL import Image
import random


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "Remove image")
        panel = MainPanel(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(panel)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    """Create a panel class to contain screen widgets."""
    def __init__(self, frame):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, frame)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self._on_paint)
        cmd_refresh = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_REFRESH)
        cmd_refresh.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self._on_cmd_refresh_click)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add((500, 300))
        sizer.Add(cmd_refresh, flag=wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER, border=10)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.x_pos = random.randint(0, 100)
        self.y_pos = random.randint(0, 100)

    def _on_paint(self, event):
        bitmap = self._get_image()
        self._draw_image(bitmap)

    def _get_image(self):
        bitmap = wx.Bitmap()
        bitmap.LoadFile("red.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        self.image_width = bitmap.GetWidth()
        self.image_height = bitmap.GetHeight()
        return bitmap

    def _draw_image(self, bitmap):
        dc = wx.ClientDC(self)
        dc.DrawBitmap(bitmap, self.x_pos, self.y_pos, True)

    def _on_cmd_refresh_click(self, event):
        del event
        colour = (212, 212, 212)
        blank_image = Image.new('RGB', (self.image_width, self.image_height), colour)
        bitmap = wx.Bitmap.FromBuffer(self.image_width, self.image_height, blank_image.tobytes())
        self._draw_image(bitmap)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    screen_app = wx.App()
    main_frame = MainFrame()
    screen_app.MainLoop()
```

[EDIT 29 Dec 17: change wx.PaintDC to wx.ClientDC]

Comment: your code fails with:  
`File "P:/Python36/programas/test/test.py", line 42, in _draw_image
    dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
wx._core.wxAssertionError: C++ assertion "Assert failure" failed at ..\..\src\msw\dcclient.cpp(277) in wxPaintDCImpl::wxPaintDCImpl(): wxPaintDCImpl may be created only in EVT_PAINT handler!`

Comment: Works for me on Python 3.5.2, wxPython 4.0.0b2 gtk2 (phoenix)

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04. I will test on Windows

Comment: Strange, in `on_cmd_refresh_click` you call `_draw_image` where you instantiate a `wx.PaintDC`. At least on windows you cannot call `wx.PaintDC` outside a `EVT_PAINT` event handler. That is what the Error is also saying.

Comment: Works for me on Windows Python 3.5.4, wxPython 4.0.0b2 msw (phoenix). The docs do say: "A wx.PaintDC must be constructed if an application wishes to paint on the client area of a window from within an EVT_PAINT() event handler". I took that to be a sufficient condition rather than a necessary one. However, I've changed the code in the question to wx.ClientDC. Is that better?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to `Refresh` your `Panel` without redrawing the bitmap. You will get your `Panel` background style in the place of the picture. This would work for your current code (fixed-size `Panel`) but not for a `Frame` that could be resized because this would produce and `EVT_PAINT` and you will have again your bitmap drawn. To solve this, you can use a flag to tell when you want a `Refresh` without bitmap.

Example of code could be:

```
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "Remove image")
        panel = MainPanel(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(panel, 1, wx.EXPAND)     # I made the panel expandable sizable
        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    """Create a panel class to contain screen widgets."""
    def __init__(self, frame):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, frame)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self._on_paint)
        cmd_refresh = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_REFRESH)
        cmd_refresh.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self._on_cmd_refresh_click)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add((500, 300))
        sizer.Add(cmd_refresh, flag=wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER, border=10)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.x_pos = random.randint(0, 100)
        self.y_pos = random.randint(0, 100)
        self.refresh = False            # flag to control drawing of  bitmap

    def _on_paint(self, event):
        if self.refresh: return         # for a clean background, return
        bitmap = self._get_image()
        self._draw_image(bitmap)

    def _get_image(self):
        bitmap = wx.Bitmap()
        bitmap.LoadFile("mypng.PNG", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        return bitmap

    def _draw_image(self, bitmap):
        dc = wx.ClientDC(self)
        dc.DrawBitmap(bitmap, self.x_pos, self.y_pos, True)

    def _on_cmd_refresh_click(self, event):
        self.refresh = True        # forget the bitmap
        self.Refresh()             # and refresh the screen
```

Another option is to create a `Bitmap` of size 0 to replace the original one. Note that for this you have to decouple the `_on_paint` call from the reading of the bitmap. Otherwise you will re-read the original picture each time you resize your window:

```
class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    """Create a panel class to contain screen widgets."""
    def __init__(self, frame):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, frame)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self._on_paint)
        cmd_refresh = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_REFRESH)
        cmd_refresh.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self._on_cmd_refresh_click)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add((500, 300))
        sizer.Add(cmd_refresh, flag=wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER, border=10)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.x_pos = random.randint(0, 100)
        self.y_pos = random.randint(0, 100)

        self._get_image()

    def _on_paint(self, event):
        self._draw_image()

    def _get_image(self):
        self.bitmap = wx.Bitmap()
        self.bitmap.LoadFile("mypng.PNG", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)

    def _draw_image(self):
        dc = wx.ClientDC(self)
        dc.DrawBitmap(self.bitmap, self.x_pos, self.y_pos, True)

    def _on_cmd_refresh_click(self, event):
        self.bitmap = wx.Bitmap(0,0)
        self._draw_image()
        self.Refresh()
```